# Limit point of sin function in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

If a set $S= \sin(n\pi/2)$ and $n$ is Natural number, then what would be its limit point. I assume that it's limit point should be Null set because this set is finite set having only $3$ real values {$-1,0,1$}. Can any one bags to differ, because answer seems to be that these $3$ points are limit points.

Comment: What is the definition of a limit point of set?

Comment: A limit point for a set is that point whose member of its neighborhood are in the set ( not necessarily all members) except that particular point.

Comment: Yes, there are no limit points, if your definition is that every neighborhood of a limit point contains a point of the set in question. Finite sets have none.

Comment: But you have infinitely many elements of the sequence in each of the neighborhoods. Limit point of set and limit point of sequence have different definitions. To make them compatible, think of the limit points of the pairs $(\frac1n, a_n)$, then the limit points $(0,x)$ of the set of pairs are 1-to-1 to the limit points $x$ of the sequence.

Comment: Got it. Each element is repeated infinite times and so neighborhood contains infinite element . Thanks every

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right. Consider $a_n=\sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right) $ for $n=k$ ,for $n=k+1$ , for $n=k+2$  and for $n=k+3$. Then you split your sequence into 3 subsequences which one of them converges to 1,0,-1 respectively. In this kind of problems you need to take the subsequences $mod 2\pi $  in order to find alla limit points. For example if you have $b_n=\cos(n \pi / 6 ) $ you have to consider 12 subsequences in order to cover all the cases . On the other hand if you have $c_n=\sin(n) , n\in \mathbb{N}$  then this is a real problem. Someone needs to use special techniques to show that every point of $[-1,1]$ is a limit point of $c_n$

Comment: For $\sin n$ you only need that the lattice in $\Bbb R$ generated by $1$ and $r$ is dense if and only if $r$ is irrational. It follows that $n \mod 2\pi$ is dense in $(0,2\pi)$ etc.

Comment: I already know that , i just tried to cover all cases in this kind of excercises. This problem is not considered as an elementary one , in contrast with the first two cases that i stated above.

Comment: Ok. I only wrote that because "special techniques" sounded slightly prohibitive, and this theorem by Kronecker/Minkowski(?) is not much harder than the diverse compactness related theorems in metric space theory.

Comment: Yes you are right. I really did not mean to scare him !